# element "iframe" undefined - Errors found while checking this document as XHTML 1.0 Strict!

Tags: css, xhtml, w3c-validation

My website http://sbmcrushers.net can't pass XHTML strict validation. What should I do?

Maybe I can use:

```
<object data="include/index.html" type="text/html"
     style="border:none; width:960px; height:244px; margin-top:-10px;"></object>"
```

But it scrolls when I use that.

Comment: Why bother about validating as XHTML strict? You're not serving the page with an XML mime type, so browsers aren't treating your page the same way as the validator anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have iframes in XHTML documents.  You can have `div` tags though, and apply `overflow:scroll` via CSS. This will cause a scrollbar to appear if the content inside them is too big for the dimensions you assign the div.

Just throw whatever content you've got in `include/index.html` (minus the html/body markup) into the page itself, inside a div:

```
<div style="width:960px; height:244px; overflow:scroll"><!-- content of index.html --></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it:

```
<object data="include/index.html" type="text/html"style="border:none; width:200px; height:90px; margin-top:0px; overflow:hidden; "></object>
```

There is no scroller.

Some overflow types:

#### visible

The overflow is not clipped. It renders outside the element's box. This is default

#### hidden

The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible

#### scroll

The overflow is clipped, but a scroll-bar is added to see the rest of the content

#### auto

If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content

#### inherit

Specifies that the value of the overflow property should be inherited from the parent element

Answer (score 2):

You could validate the page as XHTML 1.0 Transitional, or XHTML5, instead.

Strict != good.